# Uber from the airport in Prague - pickup location and reliability?

Tags: airports, czech-republic, prague, uber

My wife and I are traveling to Prague this weekend. I'm normally good with public transit, but this time around, we'll be dragging luggage, and I see that from the airport to our hotel, it's a bus to the metro, and I'm not looking forward to that after a long overnight flight.

I see that [Uber operates in Prague](https://www.uber.com/cities/prague/), but I've seen suggestions that [that's more in the city center and might not be reliable at the airport](https://www.reddit.com/r/Prague/comments/3cu6z7/uber_the_airport/cszic2j). So, questions:

1. *Is* Uber reliable at the airport?
2. Where do they pick up? With ground transport / buses? With taxis? Somewhere else?

Comment: Move the pointer to Prague's airport in Uber app, see how many cars available and the estimate time. That's the best bet..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. I've found that they're reliable during the day but can be problematic (no cars available) after midnight. In that case I recommend using their local equivalent [Liftago](https://www.liftago.com/invite/MICHAL1586) - as of 2019 they're slightly cheaper than Uber and their app is on par with Uber's.
2. In Terminal 1 they pick up from the parking lot P1 outside the arrivals hall. In Terminal 2 they pick up from outside the departures hall.

The app will tell you where you'll be picked up once you select the airport as your location:

[image]