# What are the taxi options from Prague Airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, czech-republic, prague, prg

My Dad will be arriving into Prague airport Terminal 1 at 22:40 tonight.

I called AAA taxis to book a cab but they said they can only wait ten minutes so better call them when he has picked up his luggage. If I do that, I fear that he may have to wait for a while for the taxi to arrive.

Should I simply do the above or will there be taxis at the taxi rank at around 23:00 on Sunday night?

Is it necessary to book a taxi in advance?

Comment: Prague taxi drivers are notoriously dishonest. I would pre-book. I used a service, I'll try to find name and edit. And indeed we were driven long way round by the one cab we took from a rank, even though it was a company recommended in guides.

Answer (score 7):

There are two companies that are preferred by the airport. They shall always have a car before the airport. Other taxi companies must spend less than 15 minutes at paid area so they are reluctant to wait here. They usually stay outside airport area and arrive once you are ready.

I usually order at www.modryandel.cz where I can tell my flight number and they will wait for me. No taxi in Prague can have higher price than  40 CZK entrance fee and 26 CZK per kilometer and 6 kc per minute in traffic jam. If somebody asks for more he is a thief.

You can calculate your price with this tool: http://www.cenytaxi.cz/. Odkud = from, letiště = airport, kam = to. A button "Spočítej mi cenu" means Calculate the price. As you can see the price to get from the airport to the very city center is between 330-470 CZK (plus 6 kc per waiting time on traffic lights or traffic jams).

[image]

If you order at a taxi agency they can help you in case of price dispute. They can kick out bad driver from their system so it is less risky than taking taxi on street.

Answer (score 5):

I have not experience with taxis in Prague, but I just flown there the previous weekend and can at least tell this:

- Everybody agrees that Prague Taxi drivers are mostly dishonest.
- Inside the airport, just in front of the exit doors, there are stands of one of the official taxi company (FixTaxi, if I remember correctly)
- The public transport from and back the airport is really good and cheap, you just have to change at a point to take the metro to the city, but it's a minor issue
- This is the company that the airport itself recomended: http://www.prague-airport-transfers.org/, and they have fixed prices.

So, that said, I'd point out that someone has to wait: as obvious as it can sound the plane will land when it will land and your dad will be outside the airport the moment he will be outside; what if you book a taxi, the airplane land exactly on time, and then your father is stopped half an hour for borders checking? It's a reality that can always happen to everyone.

He will have to wait for a taxi or a bus, or the taxi will wait for him. And the latter will be really expensive...

It would be better if you explained a bit more the problem you have -"I fear that he may has to wait for a while", is your dad waitophobic? Maybe he doesn't speak english? Where will you be while he will land in Prague?- but anyway, a few options:

- Public transport, take the 119 to the metro station and then the metro to the city. The metro station is a the end of the bus ride, the stop is named Nádraží Veleslavín, and when he will step down from the bus he will be in front of the metro entrance. Ticket machines are outside the airport, just in front of the exit (impossible to miss) and the bus stops in front of them, they have the choice for many languages and are really easy to operate anyway. And if your father has a contactless credit cards, it's just a matter to push one button and put the card in front of the machine. Same for metro ticket.
- Taxi and he doesn't speak english: I'd go for Prague Airport Transfers. Just ask your father to call you when he will be gone past border checking.
- Taxi and he speaks English: you still can do the same as above, or he can just book a taxi from the stands I mentioned before. I wouldn't fear him have to wait for long; taxis go where the money are, and the moment an airplane lands is money landing; I bet that there will be a few taxis outside the airport waiting for a passenger booking at the stand.

Answer (score 4):

I live in Prague and have traveled to/from the airport many times. Here are the options as of 2019:

1. Install [Uber](https://www.uber.com/invite/mmddi) on your dad's phone and show him how to use it. There is free Wi-Fi in the terminal, so he wouldn't face issues calling a cab. Be aware that Uber frequently [doesn't have cabs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74173/uber-from-the-airport-in-prague) at Prague Airport past midnight, so that's not a good option if his flight is delayed.
2. Install [Liftago](https://www.liftago.com/invite/MICHAL1586) on your dad's phone. It works in the same way as Uber, but has more cabs in Prague. As of 2019 they're a cheaper option than Uber. You get a free ride worth 400 CZK for registering, which should be enough to reach the city center.
3. Have your dad call a company called [Nejlevnejsi Taxi](http://www.nejlevnejsi-taxi.cz/en/) once he's in Prague. They have some of the cheapest rates and don't scam customers. Their phone operators speak English.

There's no need to pre-book a taxi as they're not scarce in the area of the airport. Be aware that the official taxi companies (FixTaxi and AAA) are prone to scamming tourists and I would avoid using them if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can install uber or [taxi2share](http://www.taxi2share.eu) app on your dad's phone. He can simply order taxi by clicking some buttons. They are reputed companies and their price is fixed.